# How can I create a rename script using multiple rules?

Tags: bash, rename

I constantly get a bunch of files named "Unknown.png" into a folder, and often times they get renamed "unknown (1).png, unknown (2).png" etc. This is a bit of a problem as sometimes when cleaning up files and moving them somewhere else I get asked if I want to replace or rename, etc.

So I decided to make a crontab task that renames the files to CB_RANDOM this way I don't even have to worry about potentially overwriting two files with the same name.

I could figure it so far, I find the files, replace the name Unknown to CB_ and add a random number.

the problem comes to (x) at the end of the filename. I managed to figure out also how to solve it I just strip away any parenthesis and numbers.

The problem is I can't figure out how to make the rename function to follow both rules.

```
for u in (find -name unknown*); do 
    rCode = random
    rename -v 's/unknown/CB_$rCode' $u 
    rename -v 's/[ ()0123456789]//g' $u
```

Ideally I'd like to be able to follow both rules on the same line of code, specially since once it runs the first line, then $u wont be able to find the file for the second step.

Comment: Rename the whole filename instead of the `unknown` part could solve this. `rename -v "${u}" "CB_${rCode}.png"  "${u}"`

Comment: Since you are using a loop, you could simply construct the new name using `bash` syntax and use `mv`. If you were wanting to rename a folder of files using a pattern rule, then `rename` is the tool to use.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should first be changed into

```
# find is a subcommand, use $()
# find a file with wildcard, use quotes
for u in $(find -name "unknown*"); do 
    # Is random a command? Use $()
    rCode=$(random) 
    # Debug with echo, will show other problem
    echo "File $u"
    # $rCode will not be replaced by its value in single quotes
    # Write a filename in double quotes, so it will not be split by a space
    rename -v "s/unknown/CB_$rCode" "$u"
    rename -v 's/[ ()0123456789]//g' "$u"
done
```

The new line with `echo` shows that the loop is breaking up the filenames at the spaces. You can change this in

```
while IFS= read -r u; do 
    # Use unique timestamp, not random value
    rCode=$(date '+%Y%m%d_%H%M') 
    echo "File $u"
    rename -v "s/unknown/CB_$rCode" "$u"
    rename -v 's/[ ()0123456789]//g' "$u"
done < <(find -name "unknown*")
```

I never use `rename` and would use

```
while IFS= read -r u; do 
    # Use unique timestamp, not random value
    rCode=$(date '+%Y%m%d_%H%M') 
    # construct new filename. 
    # Restriction: Path to file is without newlines, spaces or parentheses
    newfile=$(sed 's/[ ()]//g; s/.*unknown/&_'"${rCode}"'_/' <<< "$u")
    echo "Moving file $u to ${newfile}"
    mv "$u" to "${newfile}"
done < <(find -name "unknown*")
```

EDIT:
I removed a `sed` command for renaming files with `(something)` in it:

```
# Removed command
    newfile=$(sed 's/\(.*\)(\(.*\))/\1'"${rCode}"'_\2/' <<< "$u")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for such a detailed response, I've been studying the code to understand what each line does (Sorry I'm a bit new at this but I'm trying!

So first will I noticeed you replaced the FOR loop for a WHILE loop and added the find command at the end, does this still makes it apply these changes only to files named unknown*? 

The part of the code that doesnt seem to work is stripping the (x) since I get filenames similar to unknown 193145_x.png
Also it doesnt work with just unknown.png files, looks like it requires the file to have a (x) on the filename for it to work

Comment: I edited my answer, but you should prefer the solution of @DennisWilliamson.
(I replaced the FOR by WHILE for filenames with spaces, and moved the `find` to the end making it run without an addiotional subshell. Not relevant here, but variables set in a loop in a subshell will be lost when the loop is finished)

Answer (score 0):

No need for a loop:

```
find -name 'unknown*' -exec rename 's/unknown \([0-9]+\)\.(.*)$/"CB_".sprintf("%04s",int(rand(10000))).".".$1/e' {} \;
```

- `find` all the files, starting in the current directory, recursively, with names similar to "unknown (1).png"
- `rename` them with a resulting filename similar to "CB_0135.png"

This produces an error message if a filename already exists.

Comment: Oh this is a nice command, tho it only works if I add the filename at the end, it doesn't seem to be running the rename command for every file found. any idea how could we fix that?

Comment: @DaniloReyes: I'm afraid I'm not following what you mean. This command finds all the files that start with "unknown" then renames them if the match the pattern (have a number in parentheses) and have any extension. The patterns can be changed of course. But adding a filename at the end shouldn't do anything at all or should produce an error. This command works for me as-is. Did you modify it? If so, how? What is your operating system?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu, if I paste the code on the terminal right as it is, it wont rename any file. Personally I've always struggled making the find -exec command work even in other distros. 

Basically the way I got it to work was by removing the find part and adding the filename at the very end manually. 

If I remove the -exec part, it seems to actually list all the files. But both commands wont work together somehow. 

Tried putting it on a loop and feeding the file trough it to the rename line you gave me, but it either adds a ./ to the filename or crops it at (x)

Comment: After toying with the code a big, trying to fully understand how each segment works, I figured out how to make it work I just had to remove the ^ from s/^unknown then it renamed any unknown (x).png files, for the raw unknown.png file I can just modify the existing code to make it work, I think it's all good! thank you so much! 

Tho i'm very curious what the ^ was mean to do? because I find it odd that it worked with it if I use the rename command alone but failed when using it along the find command.

Comment: @DaniloReyes: Ah! Sorry about that! The caret (`^`) anchors the regex at the beginning of the string, but I failed to take into account the fact that `find` includes the path to the file in its output. In this case, it's the current directory (`./`). I'll remove the caret from my answer. Note, however, that without it, files with names as "complete unknown (1).png" will match and be renamed. It is possible to use the slash as an anchor and I may add an alternative showing that.

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification and explanation!